# How do I loop a variable properly in Powershell? (Exchange)

Tags: powershell, exchange-management-shell

I'm trying, but not so good with Powershell. I'm trying to dynamically check and create many Dynamic distribution lists in Exchange. Seeing as we have a relatively high turn-over of staff in this department, I wanted to script the creation of their groups.

Here's what I have, but the contents of each dist group is showing ALL of the staff, not filtering their direct reports. I understand why it's doing this, just not sure how to fix it in the Powershell script:

```
$users = Get-ADUser -SearchBase "OU=Sales Managers,OU=User Accounts - Canada,DC=somedomain,DC=net" -filter * | Select-object Name,DistinguishedName
ForEach($user in $users)  
    {new-dynamicdistributiongroup -name "$($user.name) - Test Dyn Distribution Group" -OrganizationalUnit "OU=User Accounts - Sales Staff,DC=somedomain,DC=net" -recipientfilter {(recipienttype -eq'usermailbox' -or RecipientType -eq 'MailUser') -and (manager -like $user.DistinguishedName)}}
```

If I replace the variables *user.name* and *user.distinguishedname* with the managers' actual name, the list creates the contents as expected.

Thank you,

Brad

Comment: `RecipientFilter` should be a **string** not a scriptblock